# Music player showing the wrong album art

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, music, music-player, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I've just transferred over 800 songs onto my Galaxy S6, all of which have album art. I used [peggo.co](http://peggo.co/) to download the songs from YouTube/SoundCloud (peggo automatically attaches the album art to the song).

However, all of my songs show the wrong album art, and more so, it's the one same album art from one album for all 800+ songs.

I tried deleting the offending album/songs and cleared the thumbnails using this suggested method, but now all the other songs use the same album art from a different song:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried following the answers to a similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63650/how-do-i-change-incorrect-album-art-on-the-default-music-player-of-the-samsung-g), but none of the solutions worked for me.

What should I do?

---

**Edit:** I think I know the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. All of the songs I downloaded using peggo.co set the Album Title to "Unknown" (or simply nothing), which would explain why all 800+ songs have the same album art. How can I fix this though?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this. As I said in my question, the problem is that all my songs had their Album Title set to "Unknown" or simply not set.

To fix this, you have to change the Album Title to something unique. Here's what I did to fix this (automatically, for all of my songs in a single click):

1. Download [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).
2. Drag all of your songs into the program.
3. In the navigation bar, click Actions > Actions.
4. Create a new action with the following settings:

   - **Name**: Name it anything.
   - Create a new step.
   - **Action type**: Format value
   - **Field**: ALBUM
   - **Format string**: `%artist% - %title%`
5. Select all of your songs in the program.
6. In the navigation bar, click Actions and then click your newly created action.

That should fix it.

Comment: Does this actually get the artist and title tags set to the right values?

Comment: Actually, this is not a fix for the main problem. Think that you have a compilation album which every song has it's own artwork. Android will still show a single album art for all of the songs; although it should show each artwork for each song separately.

Answer (score -2):

Use musixmatch player to rectify the track details along with album art

Comment: Can you link this app and explain how to use it to fix the album art?