# Android music players show wrong album artwork

Tags: music-player, mp3

I've started Googling last night on why all of the android music players show the wrong album artwork for my "Unknown" album. For example, when I play any song in this album, the big album artwork shows up, which basically shows a male rapper for like 80% of my songs. Playing music on the plane makes it look like I have a crush on this guy or something.

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is? I've searched my ENTIRE music folder for ALL instances of pictures, and there's not 1 single picture file in the entire folder. I have no idea where it's coming from.

I tried deleting the entire Music folder and resyncing it last night with my Desktop, but the album artwork came up yet again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've had this problem for awhile now and just never really looked for a solution until now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music player showing the wrong album art](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112334/music-player-showing-the-wrong-album-art)

Comment: This other thread just simply changes the album for every song doesn't it? Is that the only workaround that's really out there that you know of? Thanks for posting this btw.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get real tag info associated with the songs?